# S3 Event Prefix for Subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I set up an event listener on S3 that fires to a lambda function for ObjectCreate events. The S3 bucket considered has a subfolder `dev/subfolder-a/` and we would like to only listen to new objects created under `dev/subfolder-a/`.

We tried setting up the prefix as `dev/subfolder-a/` on the event notification, but the events never fire when we upload new files in `subfolder-a`

Now if we change the prefix to simply `dev/`, we receive the events but contains new uploaded files in all other subfolders (say `dev/subfolder-b/` and `dev/subfolder-c/`).

How can we specify a prefix for an S3 event notification to only consider events happening in a specific subfolder (or even sub-subfolders)?

Comment: How do you say event did not happen? Did you check in CloudWatch?

Comment: I was also seeing this issue, but it was because I was including a star `*` after the prefix... when removing the star it works. Prefix configuration is *NOT A REGEX*.

Comment: This happening with me also. I wanted to trigger an event only when file is placed in bucket/sub_folder_A/pathA and didn't work.

If I put only bucket/sub_folder_A worked but receive all events for all folder inside sub_folder_A

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the upload to `dev/subfolder-a/` is successful? [Documentation states that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html):-

> You will not receive event notifications from failed operations.

I just tested your workflow in the AWS Console (only difference is that my event is pushed to test SQS queue) and through some code and it worked as expected.